# Better alternative to Conditional loops in Large datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with (3374301, 25) records.
So Basically In Dataset:

```
    c1   c2    c3
0   a    x     v1
1   a    y     v1
2   b    x     v2
```

Suppose, I need to create another column with following condition:

```
If ((c1 == a) and(c2 == x) and (c3 == v1)) then c4 = True else False
```

What would be a faster way. Currently I am looping through each row in the dataset which is very slow.

Comment: `df['c4'] = df[['c1','c2','c3']].eq((a,x,v1)).all(1)`

Comment: what if the second condition is (c2!=x and c2!=z ) ? What will be the condition then?

Comment: Have a look at .query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what worked for me:

```
df.loc[(df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2;] == 'x') & (df['c3'] == 'v1)] = 'True'
```

You can give as many conditions or repeat this statement for different classes such as 'No' or 'Maybe'. But as pointed out earlier numpy.where() and numpy.assign() are just as affective or most likely even more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where()` or `numpy.select()`, which I believe are both vectorized and so should run much more efficiently. `np.where()` is where you have a single if-then, and `np.select()` can take a list of conditions and have a list of outcomes (more like `case` in SQL).

```py
df['c4'] = np.where(
                (df['c1'] == 'a') & (df['c2'] == 'x') & (df['c3'] == 'v1'),
                True,
                False
)
```

You still have the same sort of logic and checks as originally, but notice that you have to use `&` instead of `and` when combining these checks on the dataframe